# Serve Laravel application from nginx /location block (virtual host)

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04, nginx-location

I am trying to serve laravel from a /location block in a Ubuntu nginx virtual host configuration. I have the laravel application installed and working fine when accessed directly but the nginx location block seems like not doing what it is expected to do.

This works        : https://www.madol.example.com/horizontal-laravel/public/index.php

This doesn't (403): https://www.madol.example.com/horizontal-laravel/

Note: Real address omitted.

Main snippets which might be wrong:

```
root /var/www/madol.example.com;
server_name madol.example.com www.madol.example.com;
location /horizontal-laravel {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /horizontal-laravel/public/index.php;
}
```

Here is the full code from my config file-

```
server {

     root /var/www/madol.example.com;
     index index.php index.html;

     server_name madol.example.com www.madol.example.com;

     location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     }

     **# Something wrong here?**
     location /horizontal-laravel {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /horizontal-laravel/public/index.php;
     }

     location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 7d;
}

     listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
     listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/madol.madcoderz.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/madol.madcoderz.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
     include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
     if ($host = www.madol.example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot

     if ($host = madol.example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot


     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name madol.example.com www.madol.example.com;
     return 404;
} # managed by Certbot
```

Is there any other config issues apart from this in the code?

Comment: Do you want `/horizontal-laravel/` to find `/horizontal-laravel/public/index.php`? Because that's not what you have at the moment. The `index` directive is looking for a file at `/horizontal-laravel/index.php` and not finding anything.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes! That is where I would like it to go to. Also could you please explain why this current code not working? I have another config with Codeigniter and this is working- location /steller-color { try_files $uri $uri/ /steller-color/index.php; } I want https://www.madol.example.com/horizontal-laravel/ to go to /horizontal-laravel/public/index.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` directive is looking for a file at `/var/www/madol.example.com/horizontal-laravel/index.php` and not finding anything.

The simplest solution is to expand the `index` directive to look for `index.php` within the `public` folder. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

For example:

```
location /horizontal-laravel {
    index index.php public/index.php index.html;
    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could stop index processing for this `location` by removing the `$uri/` file term from the `try_files` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location /horizontal-laravel {
    try_files $uri /horizontal-laravel/public/index.php;
    ...
}
```

---

You could explicitly redirect this one URI with a `rewrite...last` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

```
location = /horizontal-laravel/ { 
    rewrite ^ /horizontal-laravel/public/index.php last; 
}
location /horizontal-laravel {
    ...
}
```

---

Finally, you could redesign the URI scheme to eliminate the `/public/` bit from being exposed. This is probably best achieved using an `alias` directive. You will need a nested location to execute the PHP scripts under the new root.

For example:

```
location ^~ /horizontal-laravel {
    alias /var/www/madol.example.com/horizontal-laravel/public;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /horizontal-laravel/public/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Notice that the `if` directives and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` uses `$request_filename` to obtain the path to the local file. You will need to check what is inside `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` to ensure it doesn't break anything.

Using `try_files` with `alias` is problematic due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Hi @Richard, I read the docs you linked and tried all the solutions one by one and the last one worked. Thank you. Any ideas why the previous ones didn't work? I am just worried if there are other problems in the configuration which will cause the server break in future.

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache between each configuration change? I did test each approach, but the last solution would be my preference.

Comment: Hi @Richard, also I find the internal links started giving 404 with the last solution though the root address works, for example https://www.madol.example.com/horizontal-laravel/chart/chartJs whereas previously link mapping for the same page was https://www.madol.example.com/horizontal-laravel/public/index.php/chart/chartJs which worked. Any fix for the internal links? I am just worried if there are other problems in the configuration which will cause the server break in future. Didn't clean browser cache though as I wasn't aware that could be the issue.

Comment: If your internal links use the `/public/` element in the URI, you should perhaps avoid the last solution.